# Can you link a MYSQL database to a pre- existing python code without having to use a python iterpretor?

Tags: python, mysql, database, pygame, interpreter

I have a coded a game using python on python shell. Now that I have reached the stage of making the sign- up page I am looking into using a MySQL database to read, write and validate the sign-up and login details input into the game screen. Most of the tutorials use an interpreter such as PyCharm but as I have already coded most of my game using just shell I was wondering what the easiest was of linking a MySQL database would be and if possible how I would go about it and if I would have to use an interpreter?
Thankyou ! :]

Comment: What do you mean "just shell" ?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack as in the general python IDLE screen which you can write code on.

Answer (score 3):

A few notes:

- PyCharm is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment)
- Python, by default has an interpreter, its going to be your version (python 3.6/3.7/3.8)

If you built your game in the REPL (Shell / active terminal), I would suggest you read the basics on how to set up a Python project.

Here's a good place to start: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/

Also, you have a long road ahead of you.  If you built a game you want others to play, you will need to have database connectivity to save state (if you want to use MySQL) with the appropriate packages (probably pyodbc) and then you'll need a crash course on how to set up a web based interface (how are people going to get to your game?)

**Answer: Set up a proper project.  Pycharm is an editor not an interpreter.**

Comment: thankyou, ill have a look and my game is for a very basic project so I do not have to link it to the web so others can access it. And sorry I mistyped I meant to say that I used the python IDLE to code my game

Comment: Fair, IDLE is still the default IDE that comes with it :)  Good luck with the project!

Comment: I have looked at the link you sent me I cannot find anything to do with MySQL and python linking. Currently, I have my game code and MySQL and workbench downloaded I am just not sure where to go next.